# Gauss law use not in free space

Tags: electric-fields, gauss-law, dielectric

[Gauss' law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%27s_law) specifies permitivity for free space. what happens if electric field is not in free space. does the law apply?

Comment: [See here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%27s_equations#Macroscopic_formulation).

Comment: Hi Paul. Gauss's law still applies. You just replace $\epsilon_0$ by the permittivity of whatever material the field is in.

Comment: @John Rennie That’s what I always thought until I stumbled across this https://stuff.mit.edu/afs/athena/course/8/8.02-esg/Spring03/www/8.02ch24we.pdf in particular look at example 4 (non conducting solid sphere).  Permitivity of free space is used for all scenarios. Am I missing something?

Comment: @BobD I think the sphere in example 4 has the same permittivity as the vacuum. At least the example does not state otherwise.

Comment: @John Rennie but the medium is solid insulation no? How can solid insulation have same permitivity as vacuum?

Comment: If I have the same charge enclosed in free space compared to another material not equal to free space and calculate the electric field according to Gauss,s integral equation then I get will get a different value? If there is a different where does the 'charge' disappear too? losses?